# Receiving an error during settimeout function calls out in every 5seconds in php codeigneter

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

Using setTimeout(), I know that this function helps to run me at a specified time. I am working on the codeigniter and during ajax call in php, i am getting error 403 forbidden.

**Below code runs when i clicked on the notification icon.**

```
$('.off-canvas-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
    
  event.preventDefault();
  $('body').toggleClass('off-canvas-active');
  load_unseen_notification(); 
});

// Close on mouseup and touchend
$(document).on('mouseup touchend', function(event) {
  var offCanvas = $('.off-canvas');
  if (!offCanvas.is(event.target) && offCanvas.has(event.target).length === 0) {
    $('body').removeClass('off-canvas-active');
  }
});


  function load_unseen_notification()
 {
     var csrfName = jQuery('.txt_csrfname').attr('name');
  var csrfHash = jQuery('.txt_csrfname').val();
  var user = jQuery('.user').text();
   
  jQuery.ajax({
   method:"POST",
    url:baseUrl+"admin/notifications_alert/"+user,
   data:{[csrfName]:csrfHash, id: user  },
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
  dataType: 'json',
   success:function(s)
   {
       console.log(s);
    jQuery('.messages').html(s.appendData);
    if(s.alerts_unread > 0)
    {
     jQuery('.count').html(s.alerts_unread);
    }
    else{
        jQuery('.count').html('0');
    }
   // location.reload();
   }
  });
   
 }
```

if we clicked on notification icon so above function load_unseen_notification runs and then
after that load_notification_count function gives that error otherwise no error.

```
/* Auto update alerts */
var interval = 10000; 
setTimeout(load_notification_count, interval);
  function load_notification_count()
 {
     //var interval = 5000;
     var csrfName = jQuery('.txt_csrfname').attr('name');
  var csrfHash = jQuery('.txt_csrfname').val();
   
  $.ajax({
   method:"POST",
    url:baseUrl+"admin/notfication_count/",
   data:{[csrfName]:csrfHash  },
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
  dataType: 'json',
   success:function(s)
   {
       //console.log(s);
    //$('.messages').html(s.appendData);
    jQuery('.txt_csrfname').val(s.token);
    if(s.alerts_count > 0)
    {
     jQuery('.count').html(s.alerts_count);
    }
    else{
        jQuery('.count').html(s.alerts_count);
    }
   // location.reload();
   },
   complete: function (s) {
                    // Schedule the next
                    setTimeout(load_notification_count, interval);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){alert(thrownError);}
  });
   
 }
setTimeout(load_notification_count, interval);
```

So what's happening , load_notification_count() runs perfectly but when i clicked on the notification icon (load_unseen_notification)function triggered after that load_notification_count functions gives me error of forbidden 403. I am not sure why it's happening. Can someone help me on that ?

I tried to add csrf token but nothing happened same error occured.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCAt3.png) If i disabled settimeout function then all things work perfectly but i need to update counter for that purpose i am using settimeout function for ajax call every 10seconds.

Comment: there may be a  issue you are using the  post method  &
  var csrfName = jQuery('.txt_csrfname').attr('name');
  var csrfHash = jQuery('.txt_csrfname').val();
  var user = jQuery('.user').text();    are not getting every time so getting error

Comment: In `load_notification_count` you are not passing a user parameter like in `load_unseen_notification` is that maybe your error?

Comment: @LalitKumar i am getting value evertime for user. when load_unseen_notification funcation ran and then run load_notification_count on second time then it gives me an error 403 code

Comment: @johnSmith no that's not the problem I tried with and without it. Still same issue. Usually this error occurs when we are not passing csrf token in codigneter ajax call but i am passing it. problem remains same